# Selecting a period in field based on range

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

Thank you all in advance for any help. I'm Still very new to access and have no idea where to start to find a solution. 
What I am trying to do is to auto populate a field in my table called "Period". I would like to have it use the "Activity_Date" to look into a different table that has date ranges that reference to the correct period. Based on which "Period" the "Activity_Date" falls under will return the correct "Period". I've tried using calculated data type and queries and I feel no closer to an answer than when I started.

Thanks again for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I would question why you NEED to populate the field period in your table.
In short, I wouldn't bother.
The period it is in can be derrived from the activity date field that is in the same record.

So you can write select statements that calc the period for the record in your MyTable as required.

```
    SELECT TableWithPeriods.period, MyTable.activity_date
    FROM  MyTable
          LEFT JOIN TableWithPeriods
          ON MyTable.activity_date 
             BETWEEN TableWithPeriods.StartDate 
                 AND TableWithPeriods.EndDate
```

If you need to access the period a lot then there is an argument for keeping a period value in the MyTable in step with the TableWithPeriods.

Keeping in step could be akward though as what if someone changes one of the period 's dates?

Keeping in step might mean writing a bit of SQL to update ALL MyTable rows that wither do not have the period set or when the period is now different.
A VBA update statement will look a bit like the SELECT above.
Or 
you could use database the onchange macros that respond to data being added or updated in the MyTable  (and the TableWithPeriods, if users can change dates).

Anyway, there's my opinion.  I would NOT copy the value over.

PS I'm not 100% sure about the SQl I gave above, this might work though

```
    SELECT TableWithPeriods.period, MyTable.activity_date
    FROM  MyTable
          LEFT JOIN TableWithPeriods
          ON ( MyTable.activity_date >= TableWithPeriods.StartDate 
                 AND MyTable.activity_date <= TableWithPeriods.EndDate )
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I'm not entirely sure what your suggestion is. We run off a 28 day period and I am using a reference to the period in a SQL. All I'm trying to do is save the step of having to manually enter in the correct period. Is there not a simple way to do this?

Comment: My point is there is no need to enter the period.  Just enter the date!  You could write VBA code (or SQL) to look up the period and display it in the form in a (unbound) control next to the date BUT you DO NOT have to store the period it in the table!  (Only store period in the period table!)  
(You could base your form on SQL that looks up the period so the period is displayed in a bound control that is locekd, as it gets it;s value lookedup from the SQL underlying the form -that looks up the period in the periods table using the date - like the SELECT I wrote above).